# Decode obfuscated PHP source code

Tags: php, character-encoding

How can I rewrite each file into readable code?

For example in the source code there's variables like this:

```
${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71"]="va\x6cu\x65";
```

How can I convert that into readable code such as:

```
$somevariable = "somevalue";
```

Comment: thats a code obfuscated not utf-8 realated

Comment: That sounds like obfuscated source code to me - someone explicitly doesn't want you to do this. If you insist on reverse engineering this, [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) is probably the way forward...

Comment: `$GLOBALS["yardspq"] = "value";` isn't much better, really. You can simply replace all occurrences of `\xNN` with `chr(NN)`, but even if you do that, you still won't have a very readable script.

Comment: @Radu the files aren't that big.  Refactoring should be a breeze, really.

Comment: Hmm, there may be legal implications regarding this. If you've accepted a license agreement for web-based software you've purchased, then reverse-engineering may go against that.

Comment: @halfer this isn't enterprise code or copyrighted. My friend did this to his project and didn't save his code. I wanted to take a fragment of his source but he gave me a bunch of files that were off his ftp; full of this. :/

Comment: @Kyle, a better alternative would be to ask him how he encoded them, because he might actually have a decoding tool.

Comment: D'oh! Okay cool, best of luck decoding then :)

Comment: if it was obfuscated, it was for purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not UTF8, that's just some obfuscation someone thought of to make the script less readable. You can convert every string to its character representation. For instance `\x41` means 'captial A'.

You don't have to convert these values yourself. When you echo the string, it will show its actual value.

The accolades are just a way to use a string value for a variable name, so
`${'foo'} = 10;` will set the variable `$foo` to 10.

In your case, you got a script that's messing with your globals.

```
<pre><?php

//${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71"]="va\x6cu\x65";

echo
  'It means: ' .
  '${"' . "\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS" .
  '"}["' . "y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71" . '"]="' .
  "va\x6cu\x65" . '";<br>';

// = $GLOBALS['yardspq'] = 'value';

var_dump(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"});

?>
```

Comment: Indeed, you could display the whole code like this: `eval('print "'.str_replace('"','\"',file_get_contents('source_file.php')).'";');`. `eval()` is evil but also sometimes useful...

Answer (score 5):

Just replace all occurrences of `\xNN` with [`chr(NN)`](http://php.net/chr). For example:

```
$source = file_get_contents('obfuscated_source.php');
if (preg_match_all('/\\x(..)/', $source, $matches)) {
    for ($i = 0, $len = count($matches[0]); $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $source = str_replace($matches[0][$i], chr(hexdec($matches[1][$i])), $source);
    }
}
file_put_contents('source.php', $source);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make it print out the plain strings, like:

```
<pre><?php
    //${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71"]="va\x6cu\x65";
    print_r(
        array(
            "\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS",
            "y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71",
            "va\x6cu\x65",
        )
    );
?></pre>
```

To me, it resulted in:

```
$GLOBALS["yardspq"]="value";
```

[See it working...](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ia8U5F)

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP de-obfuscators (reverse PHP encoding processors)...

Searching for "PHP deobfuscator" you may find many, the list grows as it is becoming common to find such in injected files from hacked websites.

Such injections are usually mass processed, so it may be possible to find solutions by experts for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any script that "clean" an obfuscated code.

For your commnent, that line is "equal" to something like

```
$array["key"] = 'value';
```

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the direction of what type of obfuscation this is? the ${""}[""] is confusing me. The rest I can replace.

Comment: @Kyle it is valid PHP variable variable syntax. `${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4cS"}["y\x61\x72\x64s\x70\x71"]="va\x6cu\x65";` == `${'GLOBALS'}['yardspq'] = 'value';` == `$GLOBALS['yardspq'] = 'value';`