# how to reverse php obfuscated code?

Tags: php, deobfuscation, ioncube

I decode some of my ionCube encoded PHP pages but it contain code with obfuscated PHP function names:

Example :

```
_obfuscate_DRYWMSUQDzIXCSohIQMqCz0NJiIUBSIÿ("Location: error.php");
```

this is the code for header function.

```
header("Location: error.php");
```

can you anyone please explain me how to this deobfuscate this code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode obfuscated PHP source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020457/decode-obfuscated-php-source-code)

Comment: Ask who ever obsficated it in the first place

Comment: seems like this one is different, cuz this has no '\' or numbers @d4v1d :/

Comment: @Dagon : it'll be my first thing, if I know the person ... unfortunately it done by one of past employer here :/

Comment: @SasithMaduranga - but you'll have backups and version control of the original source, right? :) Encoding is great for licensing code, and useful by organsations needing to ensure that live code isn't tinkered with by developers bypassing strict change control procedures, but if you *only* have protected sources then something sounds seriously wrong with your management and development practise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display ioncube decoded php-file through PHP code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216716/how-to-display-ioncube-decoded-php-file-through-php-code)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Obfuscation is *designed* to be irreversible - if there was a method to easily reverse the obfuscation then using obfuscation would be pointless. Think of it as hashing the function name -- although it may be possible to bruteforce the original names, you'll have to put some serious effort into it, including:

- Find out which hashing algorithm is used
- Get the used obfuscation key (which was specified during the encoding)
- Bruteforce every single function name, starting from `a()` to `my_function_name_that_does_something()`

As indicated in the comments, your only realistic chance at retrieving the original source code is to contact the original developer. You wouldn't expect to gain the original source code from a binary file compiled from C code, would you?

Comment: ugh. so how PHP Processor know which function is this obfuscation statement ?

Comment: @SasithMaduranga They don't - all functions inside the project are hashed to the same obfuscated name, they don't need to know the actual function name. This breaks things like variable variables (`$$var`) and `eval()`, but these things shouldn't be used any way in "good code". System functions should still be unobfuscated and readable however, as far as I'm aware.